# Is there a way to find out the age of an AWS account?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Given a set of Amazon credentials (not the username and password, just the API credentials), is there a programmatic way of finding out when that account was created? I am guessing if the user has an EBS volume, S3 object, I could ask the date it was created. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the IAM service there a GetUser command.

That seems to be the most relevant.  If that doesn't work, then it might not be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately the accounts do not have any IAM users (and there is not a default one)

Comment: Most likely not then. I have never seen a method that would allow access to that data from the interface

Comment: Assigning the bounty to tkone even if not able to find out a way of doing it, as I am not sure by now one exists. Thanks for taking the time to respond

Comment: been looking up and down through aws docs -- i see nothing that would let you do this.  thanks for the tip.  if i see anything in my experiences i'll surely update this.

Answer (score 21):

Login to your root account or any account that has access to billing.

Then go to https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/rest/v1.0/account

You'll find the registrationDate in epoch format.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer here. This gives you the exact account registration timestamp.

Comment: Weirdly, for one of the accounts I checked this information, the oldest available bill is 6 months older than the registration date I see at that link. (The account is more than a decade old.)

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to check your registered email with subject "Welcome to Amazon Web Services" recieved from "no-reply-aws@amazon.com" email address. This will give the exact date when your account was created.

Comment: I received this : "Your Amazon Web Services Account is Ready - Get Started Now" but this works. Cheers.

Answer (score 14):

Similar to the previous comment but with an image. If you go to billing as follows:

1. Log into the aws console Open the services menu
2. Search for billing
3. Then on the right hand side, there is a billing details button
4. From there you can explore your bills, you can go as back as possible
   (which will give you the date)

[bill date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx449.png)

Comment: This is only true if you exceeded the free tier on your first month. AWS doesn't generate an invoice unless the unpaid balance is >0

Answer (score 13):

Yes there is! Open the billing console and then in Datepicker keep on going to the past, until AWS stops you from going. Then you will get the exact date of creation of account.

Comment: Payment History gets that exact date.

Comment: That is the date of your first bill, not the date of account creation

Answer (score 4):

Your AWS account gets activated with the creation of your root user account.
Hence to find out when was your root user created, follow along with the steps below:

1. Login to your AWS root or IAM account (with appropriate privileges)
2. Search for IAM service
3. On the IAM page, Click on the "Credential Report" link on the left hand side menu
4. Click the "Download Report" button
5. A CSV report gets downloaded onto your local machine. Open the report using an appropriate spreadsheet tool (like MS Excel, Numbers for mac, etc.) and
6. Locate the "root user" in the left most "user" column.
7. Now locate the third column named "user_creation_time" for the "root user" and voila -- there it is what you were looking for...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get this information from the command line would be to use the following command:

```
aws iam get-user --user-name <user> | grep -i createdate
```

Replace  with the User Name.

Comment: This only shows the <user> data, not the global information about the account.

Answer (score 0):

Logon to your AWS Account @ https://aws.amazon.com

Go to cloudshell prompt on right top or search for it in the seearch box

Excute the below at the prompt

aws iam get-user

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here.

I did use the `https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/rest/v1.0/account` method and even created some `selenium` code to help loop through hundreds of accounts. The problem with that is that you need to log in via the GUI. I was always looking for a more programmatic way of getting the results for many hundreds of accounts.

```
    driver.get("https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/rest/v1.0/account?region=us-east-1#")
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        # Check for the pre block and extract all html text within it
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//pre'))
        )
        elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//pre')
        elemText = elem.text
        print("Account information found!")
        print(elemText)
        # Extract the json registrationDate value
        registrationDate = json.loads(elemText).get('registrationDate', "Unknown")
        print("registrationDate: " + str(registrationDate))
        # Convert the registrationDate unix epoch time int to a human readable DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS format string
        registrationDate = datetime.fromtimestamp(registrationDate / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        with open(output_filename, "a+") as f:
            f.write(Id + '\t' + Name + '\t' + Network + '\t' + EnvironmentType + '\t' + registrationDate + '\n')
```

I have more recently found that using the IAM credential reports also works pretty well using these steps:

1. Generate the report `aws iam generate-credential-report`
2. Pull back the data:

```
aws iam get-credential-report --output text --query Content | base64 --decode \
| awk 'NR==1 || /<root_account>/' | csvcut -c arn,user_creation_time \
| sed 's/arn,/account_id,/g' | sed -E 's/arn:aws:iam::([0-9]+):root/\1/g' | cut -d+ -f1
```

What it does is that it uses the IAM credential report to check when the `root` user was created (that happens at the time of account creation). Then uses a few things like:

- `base64 --decode` to decode the output
- `awk 'NR==1 || /<root_account>/'` to keep the header and only capture the root account row
- `csvcut -c arn,user_creation_time` to only take the two columns

  - `csvcut` can be installed by installing `csvkit` via your package manager yum/apt etc. or even `pip install csvkit` if nothing else is available to your system.
- `sed 's/arn,/account_id,/g'` to rename the arn column
- `sed -E 's/arn:aws:iam::([0-9]+):root/\1/g'` to remove the arn junk and leave us with the account id

Example output:

```
account_id,user_creation_time
123456789098,2015-03-23T17:13:33
```

I've confirmed both methods match ;)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate To IAM section then click on 'Access Reports' and then select 'Credentials report' and click on download Credentials report, you will get root user creation date.

Answer (score -2):

Go to (replace /your-user-name):
https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users/your-user-name

Look for "Creation time" field:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km4Ep.png)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content ([under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.